# Rearranging data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reshape

I am pretty new to Javascript. My data is currently in csv format:

```
place, time, value
a, 2009, 25
b, 2009, 35
c, 2009, 14
a, 2010, 42
b, 2010, 13
etc.
```

I want to arrange the data in the format `[{'place': 'a', 'data':[{'t': '2009', 'v': '25'}, {'t': '2010' etc.` so I can make some line graphs in d3

I am currently using the below code. However, I feel like this is inefficient because if I have a fair amount of data (30 places over 40 years), javascript will be iterating over all the data 30 times. Are there other ways I should be approaching this?

```
var instlist = [{'place': 'a', 'data':[]}, {'place':'b', 'data':[]}];
var data = instlist;

for (var i = 0; i < placelist.length; i++){
for (var j = 0; j < rawData.length; j++){
    if (rawData[j]['place'] == instlist[i]['place']) {
        data[i]['data'].push({'t': rawData[j]['t'],'v': rawData[j]['v']})
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks. Cheers

Comment: Hi. What does your `rawData` array look like? Is it something like this: `rawData = [ {'place': 'a|b|...', 'data': { 't': ..., 'v': ... } }, {'place': 'a|b|...', 'data': { 't': ..., 'v': ... } }, ... ]`

Comment: This actually doesn't look that bad. One thing though, I would store `placelist.length` and `rawData.length` in variables before looping, or they will be re-calculated at every iteration.

Comment: If your data is always like this you can use some library like https://lodash.com/ for parsing and storage helpers. If you come from MVC PHP or have LINQ backlog everything will be uber easy to understand. @Andy's answer is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is a D3 question, the D3-solution is concise. If you have a separate CSV file, you can use [`d3.csv`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#csv) to load it instead.

```js
var csvString = [
  'place,time,value',
  'a,2009,25',
  'b,2009,35',
  'c,2009,14',
  'a,2010,42',
  'b,2010,13'  
].join('\n');

var rows = d3.csv.parse(csvString);
var data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d)
  {
    return d.place;
  })
  .entries(rows);

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Out of interest, does this provide the output that OP wanted: `[{'place': 'a', 'data':[{'t': '2009', 'v': '25'}` or don't you think that's necessary?

Comment: @Andy First, he told he's a beginner. Second, this is a D3 question. So I'm sure he'd like to rename ``data`` key to ``values`` key, as it's the library's way to do it. And measuring the code maintenance cost, I'd do the same thing.

Comment: @saaj Thanks for the reference to d3. I think this is exactly what I want, however I am having trouble combining this with `d3.csv`. I use `var rows; d3.csv('testcsv2.csv', function(error, input) rows = input;})` and then continue with the `var data = d3.nest()` and it tells me the array is undefined. any suggestions?

Comment: it's weird, because when i use firedebug to step through the `d3.nest` by hand it works, but when i just reload the page it doesn't....

Comment: oh whoops i had to put the nest inside the csv function (i think)

Comment: @As3adTintin Yes, you're right. You need to process the data only when it's loaded. For that purpose you provide a callback to ``d3.csv``, which is called when D3 has finished loading your CSV.

Answer (score 0):

This just uses one loop. It splits the CSV into `strArr` along the carriage returns and creates a new output array. Then it loops over `strArr` from element 1 to the length of the array (ie from after the labels), splitting the remaining elements up into a new array by the commas and pushing the each new object to the output array.

```
var strArr = str.split('\n');
var out = [];
for (var i = 1, l = strArr.length; i < l; i++) {
  var elems = strArr[i].split(',');
  out.push({
    place: elems[0],
    data: [{ t: elems[1], v: elems[2] }]
  });
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/s8sa0p1c/4/)

Answer (score 0):

First things first, I would store `placelist.length` and `rawData.length` in variables before looping, or they will be re-calculated at every iteration:

```
var instlist = [{'place': 'a', 'data':[]}, {'place':'b', 'data':[]}];
var data = instlist;

var placelistLen = placelist.length;
var rawDataLen = rawData.length;

for (var i = 0; i < placelistLen; i++){
for (var j = 0; j < rawDataLen; j++){
    if (rawData[j]['place'] == instlist[i]['place']) {
        data[i]['data'].push({'t': rawData[j]['t'],'v': rawData[j]['v']})
        }
    }
}
```

Secondly, if you're willing to change the output structure slightly, you could reduce the number of iterations considerably.

```
var instlist = { 'a': [], 'b': [] };
var data = instlist;
var rawDataLen = rawData.length;

for (var i = 0; i < rawDataLen; i++) {
    data[rawData[i]['place']].push({'t': rawData[i]['t'],'v': rawData[i]['v']})
}
```

I'm not an expert, so I don't know how much faster this will be, but it does remove a conditional and reduce the number of iterations. On the other hand, a different data structure might not work for your purposes.